# stupid css link puzzle

Tags: css, hyperlink, styles, external

Can't get the File

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rikkitikkitumbo/writersarah/master/public/allcss.css`

To work on this. It's like the file is corrupt.. and won't take.  The only content of the css file is:

`body{ color: red; }`

I can look at the response of the css file that gets loaded and it looks fine... what am I missing?!?!?!?!

```
head
  title Sarah Peters Miller
  meta name = "keywords" content = "Sarah Peters Miller freelance writer New York Times Hairpin Magazine corporate copywright author"
  meta name = "description" content = "Sarah Peters Miller freelance writer New York Times Hairpin Magazine corporate copywright author"
  meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge, Chrome=1"
  meta charset="utf-8"
  meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
  = csrf_meta_tags
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rikkitikkitumbo/writersarah/master/public/allcss.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rikkitikkitumbo/writersarah/master/public/public.min.js"></script>

div ng-app="WriterSarah" ui-view="" ng-init="authenticated = '#{@user_authenticated}'; user_email= '#{@user_email}'"
```

Comment: HTML Tags are not used properly.

Comment: but the html tags work for the js file from github...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong you are not getting this <link href='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rikkitikkitumbo/writersarah/master/public/allcss.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>  file in your html code. Right??

Comment: I am.. I can look at the response in my 'Net' section of firebug and it's the css code body{color: red;}

Answer (score 1):

check this link, that css file only contains `body{ color: red; }` really at first, but its now updating to :

```
body {
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
}
a{
color: red;
}
```

: see this link to see the current content of css file
[Public css](https://github.com/rikkitikkitumbo/writersarah/blob/master/public/allcss.css)

Also change your link to `raw.githack.com/rikkitikkitumbo/writersarah/master/public/allcss.css`

Comment: that was just me making sure the css file would do something :)

Comment: @user3583384 change you css link to raw.githack.com/rikkitikkitumbo/writersarah/master/public/allcss.css , you cant direct acces on github but try to use this link and see if its work

Comment: Wala!!  that was it... it was accessing the file... but for some reason raw.github wasn't working.  So, why does the raw.github js file work then?

Comment: @user3583384 Wala? in Filipino,it means nothing. Actually, i experience tha issue in creating a Fiddle,and using the githubusecontent, show this warning `Github is not a CDN, using it as such will cause issues with loading the file`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you have to use inverted `[" "]` instead `[' ']` commas as like this..

```
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rikkitikkitumbo/writersarah/master/public/allcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```